# React components override inside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in react.

I try to output two components with react 16+, that starting like this:

```
function InsuranceInfo(props) {...

// and

function InsuranceCustomerInfo(props) {...
```

and main component render function look like this

```
render()
{
      return (
            <InsuranceInfo args={this.state.orderIfo}/>, 
            <InsuranceCustomerInfo args={this.state.orderIfo}>
      )
}
```

when i load the page i see only last one.

can any one help please? thank you!

Comment: Wrap your components in a div, React components only should return one single component or one single array of them. Also, don't forger the closing slash in your second component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which use Fragment

```
render()
{
  return (
     <>
        <InsuranceInfo args={this.state.orderIfo}/>
        <InsuranceCustomerInfo args={this.state.orderIfo}>
     </>
  )
}
```

Or array

```
render()
{
  return [
      <InsuranceInfo key="info" args={this.state.orderIfo}/>, 
      <InsuranceCustomerInfo key="customer" args={this.state.orderIfo}>
  ];
}
```

Comment: thank you! it is work only with an example of array without key attribute

Answer (score 3):

Do not use comma (`,`) sign between component. Either wrap the returning component in some html element

```
render()
{
    return (
       <div>
         <InsuranceInfo args={this.state.orderIfo}/>
         <InsuranceCustomerInfo args={this.state.orderIfo} />
       </div>
    )
}
```

or use React Fragments:

```
render()
{
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
           <InsuranceInfo args={this.state.orderIfo}/>
           <InsuranceCustomerInfo args={this.state.orderIfo} />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: Note for the OP: The key is that `render()` must return a single component. You return multiple components by wrapping them inside some container like a `<div>` as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to achieve what you want is to use HOC (Higher-Order Components)

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for more details.

Comment: HOC's are probably more complex than what the OP needs here.